# Filtering a pandas dataframe to remove duplicates with a criterion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas dataframes, so I apologies in case there's an easy or even built-in way to do so.

Let's say I have a dataframe `df` with 3 columns `A` (a string), `B` (a float) and `C` (a bool). Values of column `A` are not unique. `B` is a random number and rows with same `A` value can have different values of `B`. Columns `C` is `True` if the value of `A` is repeated in the dataset.

An example

```
|   | A   | B   | C     |
|---|-----|-----|-------|
| 0 | cat | 10  | True  |
| 1 | dog | 10  | False |
| 2 | cat | 20  | True  |
| 3 | bee | 100 | False |
```

(The column `C` is actually redundant and could be obtained with `df['C']=df['A'].duplicated(keep=False)`)

What I want to obtain is a dataframe were, for duplicated entries of `A` (`C==True`), only the row with the highest `B` value is kept.

I know how to get the list of rows with maximum value of `B`:

```
df.loc[df[df['C']].groupby('A')['B'].idxmax()]   #is this the best way actually?
```

but what I want is the opposite: filter `df` so to get only the entries not duplicated (`C==False`) and the duplicated ones with the highest B.

One possibility could be to concatenate `df[~df['C']]` and the previous table but is it the best way actually?

Comment: So you don't want the rows where C == False?

Comment: Yes I want the rows were `C == False` and, if `C==True`, only the row with max B is kept. In the example above, rows 1,2,3 and not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
res = df.iloc[df.groupby("A")["B"].idxmax()]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
     A    B      C
3  bee  100  False
2  cat   20   True
1  dog   10  False
```

Comment: that should be `.loc` though, it works with `.iloc` only if the index is 0, 1 ... N-1

Comment: What if two rows have the same `B` value? Is `idxmax()` returning only one of them?

Comment: Yes idxmax will return only one of them